# How can I find a struct in array using an element of that struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

For example, say I have a struct that represents a person and contains their name and age. I have an array of people, and now I want to find the person in that array that matches the name "John Doe". Doing some preliminary research has led me to `Array.Find`, but the way the documentation puts it is confusing. If someone can help me with this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can more easily use LINQ. First add `using System.Linq` and then write the following:

```
var john = people.FirstOrDefault( p => p.Name == "John Doe" );
```

Using `Array.Find` you would do:

```
var john = Array.Find( people, p => p.Name == "John Doe" );
```

I usually prefer the LINQ approach because it is more direct and readable as you can call the `FirstOrDefault` method directly on the array itself. Moreover you can use `SingleOrDefault` if you want to make sure there is only one instance that matches or throw exception or use `First` and `Single` to throw when nothing is found. The `...Default` versions of these methods return `default(T)` when no match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.Single(foo => foo.bar == "What you want.")` from the linq extension methods on IEnumerable.

**see:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an implementation of `Array.Find`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/paV9d7) for you

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var people = new [] {
            new Person("Caleb"),
            new Person("Martin"),
            new Person("Shaun"),
            new Person("Nechemia")
        };

        var result = Array.Find(people, person => person.Name == "Caleb");
        Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
    }
}

public struct Person
{
    public readonly string Name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

`Array.Find` takes two arguments: the array to search and a predicate to run on each element.

A [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) is any function or method that takes an argument (`person`), checks it against a condition (`person.Name == "Caleb"`), and returns true or false.

In this case, `Array.Find` takes the array of people, checks them one at a time against the condition that the predicate defines, and returns the first person that meets that condition.